# Talend Java - create a hashmap with start ID, end ID and thread num for every 4M rows

Tags: java

Its a Talend java component where globalMap is a hash map.
I get the maximum id from a table and wanted to build a hash map from start ID=1 till endID(select max(id) from table;) for every 4 M.

This is the below code and I get the error - Local variable - tLoop_0 should be declared final

```
private final java.util.Map<String, Object> globalMap = new java.util.HashMap<String, Object>();
```

Assiging startID and endID to hashmap to use later:

```
globalMap.put("startID", "1"); 
globalMap.put("endID", "4065055001");
```

Building the sharedList which will contain List( Map(startID="1", endID="4000001",threadNum="1"), Map(startID="4000001", endID="8000001", threadNum="2")...so on)

```
java.util.List<java.util.Map<String, String>> sharedList=new java.util.ArrayList<java.util.Map<String, String>>();
```

Assigning startID and endID for every 4M rows:

```
int cntThread=0;
    long tLoop_0 = 1;
    long tLoop_1 = tLoop_0 + 40000000;
    while (tLoop_1 <= Long.parseLong((row1.maxID).toString())){globalMap.put("threadCount",String.valueOf(cntThread));
    sharedList.add(new java.util.HashMap(){{
        put("start_id",String.valueOf(tLoop_0));
        put("end_id",String.valueOf(tLoop_1));
        put("threadNum",(String)globalMap.get("threadCount"));   
    }}
    );
    cntThread++;
    tLoop_0 = tLoop_1;
    tLoop_1 = tLoop_1 + 40000000;
```

Please suggest a better way to write this code?

At the end the output should be in sharedList format to be used in other components.

Thanks.

Comment: Get rid of the double brace initialization of the HashMap. It's a wasteful gimmick and it is the cause of your error here.

Answer (score 1):

The error you got `Local variable - tLoop_0 should be declared final` is caused by capturing `tLoop_0` and `tLoop_1` variables by anonymous class `new java.util.HashMap(){{..}` and they are should be a final or effective final (shouldn't be reassigned later).

try this one:

```
int cntThread = 0;
    long tLoop_0 = 1;
    long tLoop_1 = tLoop_0 + 40000000;
    while (tLoop_1 <= Long.parseLong((row1.maxID).toString())) {
      globalMap.put("threadCount", String.valueOf(cntThread));

      HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<>(3);
      map.put("start_id", String.valueOf(tLoop_0));
      map.put("end_id", String.valueOf(tLoop_1));
      map.put("threadNum", String.valueOf(cntThread));

      sharedList.add(map);
      cntThread++;
      tLoop_0 = tLoop_1;
      tLoop_1 = tLoop_1 + 40000000;
```